# Django's STATIC_URL and Ajax requests

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My web page makes an AJAX call to the server to dynamically select an image for display. The problem I've run into is that the `STATIC_URL` variable evaluates to an empty string, and so the image fails to load.

This is the code I'm using the render the path to the image.

```
text = "<img src=\"{{ STATIC_URL }}/images/%s\"> %s" % (ball_file, val)
t = Template(text)
tt = t.render(Context())
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why even use Template ? Wouldn't this work ?

```
from django.conf import settings

text = u'<img src="%simages/%s"> %s' % (settings.STATIC_URL, ball_file, val)
```

Note that `STATIC_URL` should contain the trailing slash, hence `%simages` in this example instead of `%s/images`.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't supplied any context for that template, so naturally all variables including STATIC_URL will resolve to empty. If you use a RequestContext, then the context processors will be run first, and therefore extra items like the static URL (and the user, and various other things) will be available.

However I agree with jpic, you'd be better off doing this directly in Python.